# NPM install not downloading Underscore.js and underscore-min files

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angular web application using VS2015 and which is using underscore": "^1.9.0". When i install NPM,  underscore.js and underscore-min.js not getting downloaded. 
Please let me help me to resolve this problem.

Windows 10 machine.node js installed.

package.json contains "underscore": "^1.9.0".

Answer (score 0):

> When i install NPM

Try running `npm install` and post the log.